# Android NDK application: AndroidManifest.xml not loaded

Tags: android, c++, xml, android-ndk, apk

Written an Android NDK application, that builds correctly and generates the corresponding shared libraries.

With this command it should produce an APK package:

`android update project --name AndroidTest --path . --target 6`

However I noticed that the "AndroidManifest.xml" is not loaded (corrupting it generates no error), and no APK package is produced.

This is the output I get:

> Updated project.properties
>   Updated local.properties
>   Updated file ~\AndroidTestProject\build.xml
>   Updated file ~\AndroidTestProject\proguard-project.txt

How can I get the APK package?

Comment: _"With this command it should produce an APK package:
`android update project`"_ How were you led to believe that? `android update project` doesn't build your project, it just generates some files that are used when building.

Comment: @Michael: ["If you're up grading a project from an older version of the Android SDK or want to create a new project from existing code, use the `android update project` command to update the project to the new development environment."](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject)

Comment: Right. It says nothing about the project being built.

Comment: That's because at that stage the project must be already built, with `ndk-build`, and the shared libraries must be available.